# Can't make dates appear on x-axis in pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, date, matplotlib, graph

So I've been trying to plot some data. I have got the data to fetch from a database and placed it all correctly into the variable `text_`. This is the snippet of the code:

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from dateutil.parser import parse

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Twin the x-axis twice to make independent y-axes.
axes = [ax, ax.twinx(), ax.twinx()]

# Make some space on the right side for the extra y-axis.
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

# Move the last y-axis spine over to the right by 20% of the width of the axes
axes[-1].spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.2))

# To make the border of the right-most axis visible, we need to turn the frame on. This hides the other plots, however, so we need to turn its fill off.
axes[-1].set_frame_on(True)
axes[-1].patch.set_visible(False)

# And finally we get to plot things...
text_ = [('01/08/2017', 6.5, 143, 88, 60.2, 3), ('02/08/2017', 7.0, 146, 90, 60.2, 4), 
         ('03/08/2017', 6.7, 142, 85, 60.2, 5), ('04/08/2017', 6.9, 144, 86, 60.1, 6),
         ('05/08/2017', 6.8, 144, 88, 60.2, 7), ('06/08/2017', 6.7, 147, 89, 60.2, 8)]
colors = ('Green', 'Red', 'Blue')
label = ('Blood Sugar Level (mmol/L)', 'Systolic Blood Pressure (mm Hg)', 'Diastolic Blood Pressure (mm Hg)')

y_axisG = [text_[0][1], text_[1][1], text_[2][1], text_[3][1], text_[4][1], text_[5][1]] #Glucose data
y_axisS = [text_[0][2], text_[1][2], text_[2][2], text_[3][2], text_[4][2], text_[5][2]] # Systolic Blood Pressure data
y_axisD = [text_[0][3], text_[1][3], text_[2][3], text_[3][3], text_[4][3], text_[5][3]] # Diastolic Blood Pressure data


AllyData = [y_axisG, y_axisS, y_axisD] #list of the lists of data

dates = [text_[0][0], text_[1][0], text_[2][0], text_[3][0], text_[4][0], text_[5][0]] # the dates as strings
x_axis = [(parse(x, dayfirst=True)) for x in dates] #converting the dates to datetime format for the graph

Blimits = [5.5, 130, 70] #lower limits of the axis
Tlimits = [8, 160, 100] #upper limits of the axis

for ax, color, label, AllyData, Blimits, Tlimits in zip(axes, colors, label, AllyData, Blimits, Tlimits):
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y')) #format's the date
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
    data = AllyData
    ax.plot(data, color=color) #plots all the y-axis'
    ax.set_ylim([Blimits, Tlimits]) #limits
    ax.set_ylabel(label, color=color) #y-axis labels
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=color)
axes[0].set_xlabel('Date', labelpad=20)
plt.gca().set_title("Last 6 Month's Readings",weight='bold',fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

The code currently makes this graph:
[Graph with no x-values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXwX6.jpg)

I understand the problem is probably in the `ax.plot` part but I'm not sure what exactly. I tried putting that line of code as `ax.plot(data, x_axis, color=color` however, this made the whole graph all messed up and the dates didn't show up on the x-axis like i wanted them to.

Is there something I've missed?
If this has been answered elsewhere, please can you show me how to implement that into my code by editing my code?

Thanks a ton

Comment: I fear this cannot be answered, because we don't know what the `text_` is. When asking about a problem with a code, always make sure you provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Ok, a little better. What is `parse`? (Be reminded that as long as you don't provide a [mcve], people will just keep asking questions in the comments until there is a [mcve], so you might just provide it directly.)

Comment: Parse is used to convert the string date to datetime format for python to understand when graphing. It is not a function made by me.
https://chrisalbon.com/python/strings_to_datetime.html

Comment: Ok, so what is `axes` then?

Comment: Shall i just post my whole code? I thought it may be too much for the answer.

Comment: No, we don't want your whole code. We want a [mcve] of the issue. Or better, *you* want to provide such example, because you are the one who wants help and in order to help we need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I feel now it may become easier to provide an answer. I have included an image of how the graph comes out.

Comment: Code rolled back for consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `x_data` is never actually used in the code. Instead of

```
ax.plot(data, color=color)
```

which plots the `data` against its indices, you would want to plot the data against the dates stored in `x_axis`.

```
ax.plot(x_axis, data, color=color)
```

Finally, adding `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` just before `plt.show` will rotate the dates nicely, such that they don't overlap.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this solved it. The issue was i was entering `ax.plot(data, x_axis, color=color)` instead. The arguments were in the wrong order. Also, any idea on how to add minor gridlines and how to make the axis show more numbers so instead of 5.5 jumping to 6. Increment the axis in 0.1 and by 1 on the other 2 axis. Thanks

Comment: I guess that is a different issue, independent on dates and multiple axes. There should be a lot of similar questions already about tick density and gridlines; if you can't find a solution, ask a new, very specific question (and make sure to stick to [ask] and provide a [mcve]).